# In Excel, how do I determine if a specific cell with multiple values contains a specific value?

Tags: excel

I have a cell that contains multiple values separated by commas (eg. 8,13,27,45).  I want to return a value such as TRUE or "X" if that cell contains a given value.  For instance, in the above example, if I want to determine if that cell contains a value of 1, it would return FALSE or " ".  If I want to determine if I contains the value 13, it would return TRUE or "X".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Programmatically or using excel functions? If you are using excel function IF and SEARCH will do it for you. Something like: `==IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1",A2)),"True", "False")`

Comment: the problem with that is that it will return on the example string (eg. 8,13,27,45) due to an "1" being present on the "13"

Comment: @OP you have to be a little more specific on regards what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

As a formula, adding trailing-leading `,` to mark delimiters so exact matches work;

```
=IF(ISERR((SEARCH(","& "what_to_find" &",",","& A1 &","))), "FALSE", "TRUE")
```